# List with image in between

Tags: html, css, image, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have a horizontal list with 5 items in it, in the center list item I have an image. My question is how do I move my other list items up without the image going up and above the screen. Hard to explain but if you see my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c1fodk6z/1/#&togetherjs=0c3MNG4Teb).

Snippet:

```css
ul {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: -70px 55px 30px 55px; /*if I reduce the top margin the image will be cut from the top */
}

.logo img {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>This</li>
  <li>This</li>
  <li><img class=" logo" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></li>
  <li>This</li>
  <li>This</li>
</ul>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c1fodk6z/1/#&togetherjs=0c3MNG4Teb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use *margins* - use [*`vertical-align`*](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp).

See demo below where I use `vertical-align: top` (the default is `baseline`):

```css
ul {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
.logo img {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>This</li>
    <li>This</li>
    <li>
      <img class=" logo" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </li>
    <li>This</li>
    <li>This</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Ah thanks, "vertical-align:middle" is what i was after.

Answer (score 2):

```
li {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

but you now need to adjust for your margins
(first time here btw)that fiddle, when loads of people on it .. is freaky